# jQuery run ajax when span value changes

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I am using x-editable. I read the docs but I couldn't understand how to implement it. http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html

I want my ajax call run when I change a value of a span in the table, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Here's my current script. What I want to do is to be able to update certain elements based on their classes. For instance, when I change the value of the email (it has a class called email), I will run an ajax call that changes email address. The same applies to name and password, but I don't know how to detect changes on these values.

HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id="datatable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Your name</td>
            <td><span class="xedit name"><?php echo $name; ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><span class="xedit email"><?php echo $user_email; ?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><span class="xedit password"><?php echo $password; ?></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    $('.xedit').editable();
    $(document).on('click', '.editable-submit', function () {
        var y = $('.input-sm').val();
        var z = $(this).closest('td').children('span');
        $.ajax({
            url: "process.php?data=" + y,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (s) {
                if (s == 'status') {
                    $(z).html(y);
                }
                if (s == 'error') {
                    alert('Error Processing your Request!');
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert('Error Processing your Request!!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have zero experience, I haven't read the code, just checked the html of the pop-up...I would run the ajax after you have submitted the form:

```
$('form.editableform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit multiple times
    var x = $('.userid').val(); // it's a hidden value in the page, so userid is static for each update.
    var y = $('.input-sm').val();
    var z = $(this).closest('td').children('span');//This is not okay
    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php?id=" + x + "&data=" + y,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (s) {
            if (s == 'status') {
                $(z).html(y);
            }
            if (s == 'error') {
                alert('Error Processing your Request!');
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('Error Processing your Request!!');
        }
    });
    this.submit(); // use the native submit method of the form element
});
```

I'm not sure it will work (precedence or if `submit()` detects the enter key), but you can try... please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved the issue with the native solution (I should have looked into it its documentation carefully), like below. When I try to save the input with the .user-email class, the code below works.
`$('.user_email').on('save', function(e, editable) {
                alert("this is a test");
            });`